# Are there more important "impossible triangles" aside from CAP theorem, FLP impossibility and Zamfir's triangle?

Tags: blockchain, consensus

I have come across CAP theorem, FLP impossibility, and Zamfir's triangle ever since I began to study blockchain. As I interpret **CAP theorem** as the tradeoff between **consistency**, **Availability**,  and **Partition Tolerance**; **FLP impossibility** as **Determinism**, **Asynchrony**, and **Failure** which can be further categories into safety and liveness; Zamfir's triangle as **Latency**, **Message Overhead**, and **number of nodes**.
1. Is my understanding of these theorems correct?
2. Are there more impossible triangles that are important to understand blockchain?